# The same SQL statement performs different on two servers - sorting by date

Tags: mysql

I have several servers sending their hostname, IP address and CPU temperature to another server, which stores the data in a MySQL table. I want to output a table listing for each server its hostname, IP address and temperature in decreasing order of when it was last heard from.

In order to do this, I'm running this SQL statement:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM (SELECT hostname,
                 TRUNCATE(temp,1) AS temp,
                 ip_address,
                 createdtime
            FROM report
        ORDER BY createdtime DESC
         ) as tmpTable 
GROUP BY UPPER(hostname) 
ORDER BY createdtime DESC
```

This performs perfectly on one setup, but not on the other. On server one, I get this:

```
hostname    temp    ip_address  createdtime     

helium  49.2    x.x.x.x     2019-06-18 14:20:01 
neon    37.9    x.x.x.x     2019-06-18 14:20:01 
krypton 46.5    x.x.x.x     2019-06-18 14:20:01
```

On server two, I get this:

```
hostname    temp    ip_address  createdtime     

test    49.7    x.x.x.x     2019-03-22 22:25:05 
satnogs 84.8    x.x.x.x     2018-12-27 21:28:12 
radio   50.7    x.x.x.x     2018-07-04 14:18:44
```

On server two, the exact same SQL statement produces a totally different output than on server one. Plus, I can see that there are (much) newer entries for satnogs and radio - so why aren't they listed?

Can different versions of MySQL sort diffently by dates? I have no idea how to get any information about the server that works, but the one that doesn't has this info:

Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 10.3.11-MariaDB-1:10.3.11+maria~bionic - mariadb.org binary distribution
Protocol version: 10

Comment: After updating to MariaDB10.3 I discover that some "small problems" like fields without def value, writing "" for numercial field, wrong string size, etc... which didn't went wrong with previous version are now stopping the query. Maybe the server that works has an older version, accepting these "small problems" while the other one reject them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you're grouping by `hostname` but you are not telling the database server what to do with the other fields. 
I guess that you would like to get the last entry for every server, right?
In this case, you should modify your query to get only the last record per server. Something like:

```
  SELECT hostname,
         (SELECT TRUNCATE(r2.temp,1) AS temp
            FROM report as r2
           WHERE r2.hostname=r1.hostname
        ORDER BY createdtime DESC
           LIMIT 1
         ) AS TEMP,
    (SELECT r3.createdtime
            FROM report as r3
           WHERE r3.hostname=r1.hostname
        ORDER BY createdtime DESC
           LIMIT 1
         ) AS createdtime
    FROM report AS r1
GROUP BY UPPER(hostname)
```

Comment: Of course! I hadn't thought of that - thank you very much! This makes sense. Now all I need is to `ORDER BY createdtime DESC` in the end. I also put in a period between r2 and temp in line 2, but I can't edit your answer and put it in, since edits have to be at least six characters...